# Convert Java code to Coldfusion, how to work with abstract objects?

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

Took some working code from a Java 8 project, and trying to run it in CF 2018.

```
String fileName = "C:\test.txt";
File file = new File(fileName);

BasicFileAttributeView attributes = Files.getFileAttributeView(file.toPath(),BasicFileAttributeView.class);
```

With CF, so far I have only this working:

```
<cfset variables.file = "c:\test.txt">
<cfset filePath = createObject("java","java.io.File").init(variables.file)>
```

How can I create an object for BasicFileAttributeView? It's abstract.

Comment: What methods do you see when you dump variable `filePath`?

Comment: I blogged how to do this last week: https://www.petefreitag.com/item/1002.cfm